# Titlesec space issue

Tags: spacing, titlesec

```
\documentclass[11pt,]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\normalfont
\titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}%
\vspace{6pt}%
\sffamily\bfseries\filleft}
{\thesection}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{8pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
\begin{document}

\section{This is a section heading}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first item and it is too low on the page...
\item This is another item
\item This is another item
\item This is another item
\item This is another item
\item This is another item
\item This is another item
\end{enumerate}
\section{This is a section heading}

This paragraph is fine ...
\end{document}
```

Why am I getting extra vertical space before a list but not before a paragraph?

Comment: Not sure of a general fix, but you can place `\vspace{-23pt}` after the `\begin{enumerate}`.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this code between `\section{…}` and your list **without adding blank lines**:

```
...
\section{This is a section heading}
\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax}
\begin{enumerate}
...
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your suggestion: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont\titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}\vspace{6pt}\sffamily\bfseries\filleft}{\thesection}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{8pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
\begin{document}
\section{This is a section heading}
\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first item and it is too low on the page...
\item This is another item
\end{enumerate}
\section{This is a section heading}
This para is fine
\end{document}`

Comment: I tried your code, and had an error message with part of the code containing invisible characters, it seems. It compiles fine after I've deleted these characters. Could you test with the `\titleformat{…}`  command replaced with this one:  
 `\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin] {\normalfont\titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}\vspace{6pt}\sffamily\bfseries\filleft}%
 {\thesection}{.5em}{} `?    (Note: I'm `utf8` encoded).

Comment: I can't compile your code either because there is a `'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)` after `\filleft}`.  I didn't have it in my original code, sorry for inconvenience.  I post an answer and a snap shot to show what I mean.

Comment: @ArashEsbati It works fine for me.

Comment: Please do let me know if you object to my having edited your answer for clarity.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks for editing the answer above, it works without the blank line.